# Send string to a http server with JAVA

Tags: java, string, http

```
try {
        URL  url = new URL("ftp://username:password@url.net/FileToWrite.txt");
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();
        OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
        output.writeChars("hello");
        buffer.close();
        os.close();
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

this code gives me a socket exception, please help I am at a lose

Comment: Show us the exception (msg, stack trace etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Java 8:

```
        try {
            URL  url = new URL("http://cnn.com"); /* Tested on a real URL */
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
urlc.setDoOutput(true); /* Added this ... */
            OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();
            OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
            ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
            output.writeChars("hello");
            buffer.close();
            os.close();
            output.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Make your life easier by using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/